# PowerPivot Transformation Tab missing

Tags: excel, powerpivot, unpivot

I want to unpiovt some data and wanted to use PowerPivot. The last time I used it I had a tab called "Transformation" which is not there anymore. I looked around and could not find a "modify menue" Option in PowerPivot.

Does some one has a hint where I have the pimp the settings?

Thx
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...strange.

The way I opened Power Pivot over the Power Pivot Tab in Excel I do not get the Transformation tab. I've just found by accident in the contex menue of the table the option "Data from table...". When clicking on that I get a new window that looks different but is called PowerQuery Editor. And in this window I have the transformation tab...